# Trying to edit all <a> in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Trying to a add target="_blank" to all  tags using javascript in a string.

Why does this work:

```
var editdescription = itemdescription.replace(new RegExp("All","g"),"Every");
```

But not this?

```
var editdescription = itemdescription.replace(new RegExp("<a","g"),"<a target="_blank"");
```

Comment: Are the quotes in "<a target="_blank"" intentional? If so, try "<a target='_blank'"

Comment: Regex was not designed for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've nested your double quotes incorrectly. Instead of

```
"<a target="_blank""
```

try escaping the double quotes:

```
"<a target=\"_blank\""
```

The way you wrote it was treated as two separate strings, `"<a target="` and `""` with `_blank` in between.

And as stated so many times before, preferably [don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/885443).

Comment: fantastic - thank you! Excuse my ignorance but why do the forward slashes work?

Comment: @danssker With the *backslashes* you escape the quotes and thus tell javascript that they should be treated as characters and not as the beginning/end of a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to process HTML with regex, as there are too many things that could go wrong. In this case, what if you have the tag as `<A HREF...>`? Or what about other tags that start with `a` such as `<area>`, `<abbr>`, `<acronym>` and so on? What if there's already a `target` attribute?

Instead, try treating the HTML as HTML and not as plain text. You have an engire engine at your fingertips.

```
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = itemdescription;
var links = tmp.getElementsByTagName('a'), l = links.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    links[i].setAttribute("target","_blank");
}
editdescription = tmp.innerHTML;
```

Comment: This is what I used successful before, but I had no success getting it to work from within another loop. And I 'm fairly sure that there no other targets because the string comes out of Google feed Api which seems to strip them all out for some reason.